# How to correctly use GitHub

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a private (paid) GitHub repository
It enables me to have 5 total amount of repositories in it (basic account)

I have created a repository, in where I have created a Master, Dev, and vs1, vs2, vs3 Branch

The Idea (mine idea) is:

Master should be the "base" code of my Custom Theme, this base code is shared (and the same) over all branches

DEV Branch, is where I develop and test Master, if all good, I commit to Master.

vs1, vs2 and vs3 are more developed (advanced) versions of the Master Theme.
To specify, they are versions of Master Theme but with more functionality, different options, etc.
Of course, each vs, has also his DEV, but thats not a matter now.

Problem is:

Let's assume, I change the file structure in DEV(of master), remove some files, and add some files (or folders)
I then commit to Master.
Now Master has all newly added changes, but still keeps the older (removed in DEV) files+folders in it!

How can I "sync" Master Properly, so files that got removed in DEV are also removed in Master?

And the second issue, since I share some code across all branches, how can I simultaneously sync DEV, Master, and vs1, vs2, vs3 so they all would be "updated" with the changes I make in DEV? 
(But of course, ONLY those changes, not removing additional folders I have only in vs1, vs2, or vs3)

Let's assume I have a BUG in the base code (Master), fix it in DEV, commit it to master.

I would of course need to update all other branches too, since they all would be needing that update.

The main issue is, committing seems to ADD new data, but not REMOVE obsolete folders and files!

I searched long and far in the DOC, but somehow I am really confused who I should proceed!

Should I create different repositories and then update each one, after removing the not anymore needed files, or is there a faster and, lets be honest, more effective way to achieve this?

Writing This, I also thought of "branching" each file+folder that is shared across all versions, but that makes the mess only bigger!

Comment: I think you could benefit from some reading about *Git Flow*. Best, clearest approach to branching I could find. I'll just leave it here: http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/ .

Comment: this answers some of my doubts, thanks.

Comment: still, I am not able to have the old (obsolete) stuff removed from master, once I merge a dev or whatever into it. this is good, at some point, but bad, if I want to remove / need to remove some stuff. I guess this has to be done manually?

Comment: In *Git Flow*, your `develop` branch becomes `release` branch - which then becomes your `master` branch. Changes directly into master are limited to `hotfix`-es, which are immediately taken into `develop` branch as well. I bet you didn't do that much reading yet; but I think you will be actually quite satisfied with what it provides. It's always harder to see all the benefits at the very beginning of using something, but, I would say: start using it and over time, you will see the goodness provided by this approach. (This doesn't apply only here, BTW - I would say this applies globally).

Comment: yes, I did read what I saw on the mentioned page.
I feel, this is mostly the same as GitHub Already is, just automates a few steps, like the automated deletion of not used anymore branches (which I am not sure it's best for me as a beginner)
I will give it a try (software nr 3 now) but I feel like it won't solve the mentioned issue. thanks in any case for the info!